# Extract nested values from json in pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a json file and i have extracted the nested values as following ways, but for further nested values (for weather column) showing error message : TypeError: string indices must be integers. please find the details here:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcDIj.png)

```
import urllib.request, json 
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
with urllib.request.urlopen('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Copenhagen&appid=?&units=metric') as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
    df = pd.DataFrame(json_normalize(data))
print(df)

# to extract the nested value of list column:
pd.json_normalize(data = data, record_path = "list")
# then after another column derived of weather (from list column) with nested values.
# while extract the 2nd nested values column of weather as follows;
pd.json_normalize(data = df1, record_path = "weather")
```

**TypeError: string indices must be integers**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NB9tA.png)

Thank you for your time.

Regards
MMH

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post pictures of your code/data. Paste the code and the data as part of the question which can be copied and replicated.

Comment: Hey Mohammed, can you post some sample data? This will help to reconstruct your problem so we can help you. Also post your code. Cheers

Comment: whats `df1`? I dont think `df1` is what you think it is, that error sounds like youre working with a string when you think youre working with something else.

Comment: df1 is 2nd dataframe after extract the nested values

Comment: `json_normalize()` takes a dict or list of dicts as parameters, not a dataframe.

Comment: and if you have a dataframe, why not use dataframe methods to get the data that you need